# An Upper Bound for Entropy $H(X)$ in Terms of $\mathbb{E}(\log X)$

Tags: probability, analysis, upper-lower-bounds, entropy

Suppose that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{N}$ is a discrete random variable with PMF $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathrm{supp} p = \mathrm{range} X = \mathbb{N}$. I want to prove that

> If $\mathbb{E}(\log_2 X) < \infty$ then $H(X) < \infty$.

The first thing that comes to mind is to find an upper bound for $H(X)$ in terms of $\mathbb{E}(\log_2 X)$. Expanding the expression for each of these we have

$$
H(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p(i)\log\frac{1}{p(i)}, \qquad
\mathbb{E}(\log_2 X) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p(i)\log_2 i.
$$

I have no idea for going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only purpose is to show the implication $\mathbb{E}[\log_2 X] < \infty \implies H(X) < \infty$, here is a quick argument:

Let $\mathcal{I} = \{ i \in \mathbb{N}_1 : p(i) \leq \frac{1}{ei^2} \}$, where $\mathbb{N}_1 = \{1, 2, \ldots\}$ is the set of positive integers. Then by noting that $x \mapsto x\log_2(1/x)$ is increasing for $x \in [0, 1/e]$,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} p(i) \log_2\frac{1}{p(i)}
&\leq \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} \frac{1}{ei^2} \log_2(ei^2) \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log_2 e + 2\log_2 i}{ei^2} < \infty.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have $ei^2 > \frac{1}{p(i)}$ for $i \notin \mathcal{I}$. So by using that $x \mapsto \log_2 x$ is increasing,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i \notin \mathcal{I}} p(i) \log_2\frac{1}{p(i)}
&\leq \sum_{i \notin \mathcal{I}} p(i)[\log_2 e + 2\log_2 i] \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p(i)[\log_2 e + 2\log_2 i] \\
&= \log_2 e + 2 \mathbb{E}[\log_2 X]
< \infty.
\end{align*}

Therefore $H(X) < \infty$.

(*Remark.* The above argument actually proves an inequality of the form $H(X) \leq 2\mathbb{E}[\log_2 X] + C$ for some absolute constant $C$. Of course, this bound is far from being optimal.)

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. Can you also elaborate on a motivation for this idea? :)

Comment: @HoseinRahnama, No problem! I combined several observations: (1) We will be happy if a pointwise bound $$p(i)\log\frac{1}{p(i)}\leq C p(i)\log i$$ holds for some constant $C$, since this will immediately imply $H(X)\leq C\mathbb{E}[\log_2 X]$. However, this holds only if $p(i)\geq i^{-C}$ whenever $p(i)\neq 0$. (2) So, the main obstruction will come from the terms where $p(i)$ is much smaller than a (negative) power of $i$. This lead me to estimate the sum for $i\in\mathcal{I}$ and $i\notin\mathcal{I}$ separately.

Answer (score 3):

The paper *Wyner, A. D.,* ***An upper bound on the entropy series,*** *Information and control, 20, pp. 176-181 (1972)*  provides  a general (nonlinear) upper bounds for the entropy
$$H(\mathbf{p}):=\sum_n p_n\log(1/p_n)$$
in terms of the expectation $L(\mathbf{p})=\sum_n p_n\log n$.

The paper uses near analytical arguments that I think would be nice to discuss at MSE. In the remainder of this posting, I will elaborate a little further and derive a proof of the statement in the OP as along the way.

---

Consider the set $\mathcal{A}$ of monotone nondecreasing nonnegative sequences $\boldsymbol{a}$ such such that $\phi_a(s):=\sum_n e^{-sa_n}<\infty$ for some $s>0$.  Such a sequence necessarily satisfies $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$.

For $\boldsymbol{a}\in\mathcal{A}$, set $s_a:=\inf\{s>0:\phi_a(s)<\infty\}$. Then

1. $(\lambda_a,\infty)\subset\{s>0: \phi_a(s)<\infty\}$.
2. Clearly $\phi_a:(s_a,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is strictly monotone decreasing.
3. Extended as a complex function on $(s_a,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$, $\phi_a$ is analytic.
4. $\phi_a$ is strictly convex (for example, $\phi''_a>0$).

Define the function
$$\psi_a(s)=\frac{1}{\phi_a(s)}\sum_n a_n e^{-a_n s}$$

5. By (2), $\psi_a$ finite and differentiable on $(s_a,\infty)$ ( in fact, $\psi_a=-\frac{\phi'_a}{\phi_a}$ on $(s_a,\infty)$).

Notice that
$$\psi'_a(s)=\frac{(\phi'_a(s))^2-\phi'_a(s)\phi''_a(s)}{\phi^2_a(s)}=\frac{\Big(\sum_na_ne^{-sa_n}\Big)^2-\Big(\sum_ne^{-a_ns}\Big)\Big(\sum_na^2_ne^{-a_ns}\Big)}{\Big(\sum_n e^{-sa_n}\Big)^2}<0$$
by Cauchy-Shwartz inequality (strict inequality). Hence,

6. $\psi_a$ is strictly monotone decreasing on $(s_a,\infty)$.

Let $\ell$ be the largest integer such that $a_\ell>a_1$ (notice that $\ell\geq2$ is well defined since $a_n\nearrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$). Then
$$a_1\leq \psi_a(s)< \frac{(\ell-1)a_1e^{-a_1s}+\sum_{n\geq\ell}a_ne^{-a_ns}}{(\ell-1)e^{-a_1s}}=a_1+ \Big(\sum_{n\geq\ell}\frac{a_n}{\ell-1}e^{-(a_n-a_1)s}\Big)$$

7. By monotone convergence, $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\psi_a(s)=a_1$.

Let $p_a:=\lim_{s\rightarrow s_a}\psi_a(s)$. It follows from (6), (7) that

8. $\psi_a$ is a smooth and strictly monotone decreasing function from $(s_0,\infty)$ onto $(a_1, p_a)$ and so, it admits an smooth strictly monotone decreasing inverse $\psi^{-1}_a:(a_1,p_a)\rightarrow(s_a,\infty)$.

The following result gives an upper bound for the entropy.

> ***Theorem (Wyner)*** Suppose $\mathbf{p}$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$  for which there is a sequence $\boldsymbol{a}\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[a_X]=\sum_na_np_n\leq\beta$, where $a_1< \beta<p_a=\lim_{s\searrow s_a}\psi_s(s)$. Then
> $$H(\mathbf{p})\leq\log\Big(\phi_a\big(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)\big)\Big)+\beta\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)$$

***Proof:***
Define the probability measure $\mathbf{p}^*$ as
$$ p^*_n:=\frac{e^{-a_n\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)}}{\phi_a(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta))}$$
A simple calculation yields
\begin{align}
H(\mathbf{p}^*)=\sum_np^*_n\log(1/p^*_n)&=\log\big(\phi_a(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta))\big) +\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)\sum_na_np^*_a\\
&=\log\big(\phi_a(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta))\big) +\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)\psi_a(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta))\\
&= \log\big(\phi_a(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta))\big) +\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)\beta\\
&\geq \log\big(\phi_a(\psi^{-1}_a(\beta))\big) +\psi^{-1}_a(\beta)\sum_na_np_n\\
&=-\sum_np_n\log(p^*_n)
\end{align}

Consequently
\begin{align}
H(\mathbf{p})-H(\mathbf{p}^*)\leq \sum_np_n\log\Big(\frac{p_n}{p^*_n}\Big)\leq \sum_np_n\Big(\frac{p^*_n}{p_n}-1\Big)=0
\end{align}
where the latter inequality follows from the fact that $1+x\leq e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. $\blacksquare$

---

***Back to the OP's question***

Suppose $\mathbf{p}$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$ for which
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}p_n\log n <\infty$$

The sequence $a(n)=\log n$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$. In fact
$\phi_a(s)=\sum_n e^{-sa_n}=\sum_n\frac{1}{n^s}$ is finite on $(1,\infty)$.
Here $s_a=1$,
$$a_1=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\psi_a(s)=\log 1=0$$
and
$$p_a:=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\psi_a(s)=\infty$$
Indeed, for any integer $M>0$ and $s>1$
\begin{align}
\psi_a(s)\geq\frac{1}{\phi_a(s)}\sum_{n\geq e^M}\log n\frac{1}{n^s}\geq
M\frac{1}{\phi_a(s)}\sum_{n\geq e^M}\frac{1}{n^s}\xrightarrow{s\rightarrow1+}M
\end{align}
since $\lim_{s\rightarrow1+}\phi_a(s)=\sum_n\frac1n=\infty$ by monotone convergence.

---

***Final remarks:***

Under additional assumptions on $\mathbf{p}$ convergence of logarithmic moment is equivalent to finiteness of entropy. To be more precise, we have

> ***Corollary:*** If the $\mathbf{p}$ satisfies the additional assumption that $0<p_{n+1}\leq p_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then
> $H(\mathbf{p})<\infty$ iff $\sum_np_n\log n<\infty$

Necessity has been discussed at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4367624/121671) before. See also Theorem 1 in Wyner's paper.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this detailed and nicely explained answer. I just accepted the other one for being shorter. :)